# Better way of checking HTTP file extensions requested by clients than if blocks

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, network-programming

I am writing an `HTTP` server in `Python 2.7.8` and I check the file extension requested before sending the respond in some `if,else` blocks.

Is there a better way to this in python?

here is my code:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer


#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import cgi

PORT_NUMBER = 8080



class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index_example3.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply=False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply=True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply=True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply=True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply=True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply=True

            if sendReply == True:
                #open the static file requested and send it
                f=open(curdir+sep+self.path)
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found'% self.path)


    #Handler for the POST requests
    def do_POST(self):
       if self.path=="/send":
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile,
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type']
               })

            print "Your name is: %s" % form["your_name"].value
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("Thanks %s !" % form["your_name"].value)
            return

try:
    #Create a web server and define thehandler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('',PORT_NUMBER),myHandler)
    print('Started httpserver on port ',PORT_NUMBER)
    #wait forever for incoming http requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shuting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

Comment: BTW: in the '.js' test you also mis-typed sendReply (as snedReply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a large number of `if` tests, just split off the extension and use a dictionary lookup:

```
import os.path

extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)[-1]
mime_types = {
    'html': 'text/html', 
    'jpg':'image/jpg',
    'gif': 'image/gif',
    'js': 'application/javascript',
    '.css': 'text/css',
}
mimetype = mime_types.get(extension)
sendReply = mimetype is not None
```

Comment: what does this mean: sendReply = mimetype is not None

Comment: @AliNfr: it is a boolean test; `mime_types.get()` returns `None` if `extension` is not found in the dictionary. That means that the extension wasn't recognised, but if the test `mimetype is not None` is `True` then you do have a recognised extension.